# Did Sri Krishna have braided hair? What do our scriptures say?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, krishna, bhagavata-purana, harivamsa

I came across some Pattachitra (a form of painting from Odisha) recently that showed Sri Krishna with braided hair. I also found a statue that shows Sri Krishna having braided hair. Is there any mention of Sri Krishna having braided hair in any of our scriptures?

Pattachitra images taken from [Chitrajpur](https://www.instagram.com/chitrajpur/). Statue image taken from [Exotic India](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/product/sculptures/10-krishna-with-long-and-beautiful-braided-hair-in-brass-handmade-made-in-india-zj89/).

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: In a stotra of lord krishna his appearance is described as कुटिलालक संयुक्तम पूर्णचंद्र निभाननं .... It says that he had curly hair.